# Duplicating same helper functions over and over in D3 React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am working on a d3 react component, and am running into this issue where I have to re-define my constants and helper functions over and over again. I have the following, general layout for my d3 component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);    
    this.state = {
      chartType: 'A'
    }
  }

  getHitData() {...}
  drawChartA() {...}
  drawChartB() {...}
  drawChartC() {...}
  drawChartD() {...}
  drawChartE() {...}
  toggleButton() {...}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.drawChartA()
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { chartType } = this.state;
    if(chartType == "A") { 
      this.drawChartA() 
    } 
    else if(..B) {...}
    else if(..C) {...}
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <svg className='chart'>
          <g className='chartA' />
          <g className='chartB' />
          <g className='chartC' />
          <g className='chartD' />
        </svg>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In my actual code, in each of my different drawChartA(), drawChartB(), etc. functions, I am finding myself having to redefine both constants (chartWidth, chartHeight, padding, margin), as well as certain important d3 helper functions (colorScales, xScale, yScale, radiusScale, etc.), and this doesn't feel right. In particular, I am breaking the DRY principle.

Should chartWidth / padding / etc. constants be defined in this.state? And what should I do with all of my helper d3 functions? I don't think these should be parameters to the drawChart() functions.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should chartWidth / padding / etc. constants be defined in this.state?

No, constants should never be part of the state. Only data that changes how your component is rendered or behaves when the data is changed should be part of the state.

You can store constants as class properties and initialize them in the constructor.

Similarly you can define helper functions on the class.

```
constructor(props) { 
    super(props);    
    this.state = {
        chartType: 'A'
    }
    this.chartProperties = {
        width: 25,
        height: 30,
        margin: 35
    };
}

colorScales() { ... }

drawChartA() {
    const colorScales = this.colorScales();
    return <chart width={ this.chartProperties.width } />
}
```

Comment: this is perfect and will make my React code much better, thanks!

Comment: this.chartProperties is undefined when I try to call it in drawChartA() or any of these functions.

Comment: @Canovice it shouldn't be. Can you show your code? Are you calling the functions in your constructor before you initialize chartProperties?

Comment: revisiting to add that I addressed the issue. I was losing the scope of "this", which was the problem.